# Looking for a query to display nodes in the same level only

Tags: sql

[image]

The image above shows a Nested model tree approach. i am searching for a query that will only display level number 1 with nodes FRUIT and MEAT when FRUIT or MEAT are called

I

I have formulate a combination of children and sibilings I think to pull of Beef when Red is called as below.

```
 INSERT 



 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO categories
(categories_id, parent_id,name, parent)
VALUES('','','$name', '$parent')"; 
$enterquery = mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error()); 
$customer_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

I am looking to insert parent_id throug relating a new filled called parent that will be related to the existing field called "name" and then if parent field = to existing name field then take category_id from that name field and put it as the parent_id of the new INSERTED name.

for instance a user insert name "blue" and parent "food" then the name blue will take the categories id of food, and place it as the parent_id of blue...

Comment: What does your database structure look like? What have you tried and did not work?

Comment: my is a nested set model like

Comment: This the table data structure
    
    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
    `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `left_node` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `right_node` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

Comment: Have you tried the queries on http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html for the nested set model. The query under the section 'Finding the depth of the nodes' would seem to suit your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should restructure your data. Let the children hold the id of the parent. As it is now, I think you will have a lot of trouble building queries and even more trouble when you need to add some node because you need to recalculate the left_node and right_node values.

Here is the table structure I think you should use.

```
create table categories (
    category_id int primary key auto_increment,
    parent_id   int,
    name        varchar(255));

alter table categories
    add constraint FK_categories
    foreign key (parent_id)
    references categories (category_id);
```

Here is the code to insert your test data. (Lets keep talking food:=) )

```
insert into categories (category_id, parent_id, name)
  select 1, null, 'food'   union all
  select 2, 1,    'fruit'  union all
  select 3, 2,    'red'    union all
  select 4, 3,    'cherry' union all
  select 5, 2,    'yellow' union all
  select 6, 5,    'banana' union all
  select 7, 1,    'meat'   union all
  select 8, 7,    'beef'   union all
  select 9, 7,    'pork';
```

fruit and meat has `parent_id = 1` pointing to food etc.

The queries you need to write is a lot simpler now.

```
/* Get parent */
select P.name
from categories as C
    inner join categories as P
        on C.parent_id = P.category_id
where C.name = 'red';        

/* Get children */
select C.name
from categories as C
    inner join categories as P
        on C.parent_id = P.category_id
where P.name = 'red';        

/* Get siblings */
select C2.name
from categories as C1
    inner join categories as C2
        on C1.parent_id = C2.parent_id
 where C1.name = 'red';       

/* Get grandparent */
select G.name
from categories C
    inner join categories as P
        on C.parent_id = P.category_id
    inner join categories as G
        on P.parent_id = G.category_id
where C.name = 'red';
```

And when you need to add the color blue you only need to do this.

```
insert into categories(parent_id, name) 
    values(2, 'blue');
```

Set parent_id for blue to 2 because that is the categoriy_id for fruit.

All nodes with same grandparent as `red` except the siblings of `red`.

```
select
    C2.name
from categories C
    inner join categories as P
        on C.parent_id = P.category_id
    inner join categories as P2
        on P2.parent_id = P.parent_id and
           P2.category_id <> P.category_id
    inner join categories as C2
        on P2.category_id = C2.parent_id
where C.name = 'red';
```

Comment: This is the concept of like returning sibilings but it came empty, I am tested it in the SQL box.

Comment: I would like to know why is resulting empty in this end. you talking about same field value data?

Comment: wait I can see you have a different table structure... I see you have UNION ALL let me check the table structure.WHEre is that Union all coming from? When I inserted the values in the database I don't think I used UNION ALL, is there a way to change that now with the values inserted to see if that returns some data?

Comment: Now it is working on the SQL testing box, even when the values are different, before it was returning empty don't know why, great, But I have more color it is just returning two in this case, RED and YELLOW what about GREEN or even more. I have a question Categories as P, Categories P and Categories S are interpreted as levels or as the amount of nodes within the same level?

Comment: Something very interesting is that if there is three nodes in the same level and you specify the one in the middle then it won't pull out any of its levels, but if one in the corner is specify then it will pull up the one in the other end. for instance, RED YELLOW GREEN If I specify RED then it will pull up GREEN if I specify GREEN it will pull up RED but YELLOW will not be pull up at any instance If I specify YELLOW then it will return empty, What about if there was four the ones in the middle won't met this condition. Another thing how are this ALIASED categories interpreted like in the sql?

Comment: the table structure is above.

Comment: How to do you call the new kind of table structure, the one before the headache one lol, was a Nested table

Comment: I know it is like coming back to college, I agree let eat some left.node with some pork, lol

Comment: I meant specified node, the fish hook that makes sense.

Comment: Man you got all the fishes under your bell man. those queries work like a charm, Now I am going to work on relating on fruit with beef and beef with red, and pork with cherry, and meat with red, to pass invocies in between academics.

Comment: @Mikael 
I have formulate a combination of Sibilins and Children queries to pull of Beef when Red is a fish hook look at the query on top post.

Comment: @fello the relationship between Beef and Red is that they have the same grandparent. In fact Pork, Beef, Yellow and Red all share the same grandparent Food. So how can you know that is is Beef and not Pork you want. Or do you want all nodes that has Food as grandparent?

Comment: If fish hook "red" pull up all the grandchildren of FOOD except Red brothers.

Comment: didn't know you could use the symbol <> in sql too. it seems like most of my fellows php operators working on SQL, I will test and analize this one, indeed this table structure is easier to approach.

Comment: when you start aliasing the table categories in levels, it means one alias is a level, then the other below a deeper level, and so forth?

Comment: So in other words, the order of conditions wouldn't matter

Comment: Thanks! The following case is from fishhook Red print all Food childrens except REd's father "Fruit", Well the last query work when P2.name is SELECT instead of C.name, but the only issues is that it will print MEAT three times instead of one.

Comment: Well I have kind of fixed it, If i LIMIT 1 it will come only 1, but I don't know if I have more FOOD children then it will only print one children..

Comment: I added the fish hook red picking up meat on the edit part above. it is working now I added the <> operator.

Comment: Micheal in your opinion what are the disadvantages and advantages that both approach we have discussed and analyzed over here? for instance the Nested and this approach are different and what are the advantages that one offer and the other not?

Comment: MS SQL I think I will need that because the recursive CTe's I think will be needed.

Comment: it sounds very interesting the closure table where it builds a relationship with each individual descendant. I think that way it better because for red to establish a relationship in between beef red won't depend on fruit to establish that relationship. is it possible to establish a relationship in between red and beef if fruit is not there through adjacency?

Comment: @mikael what about if red doesn't have a parent? how can red establish a relationship in between itself and FOOD as a grandparent? in adjacency for instance.

Comment: Ok, how can I relate Food with red if Cherry was entere first? That the key question of all this case sir.

Comment: Ok, how can I relate Food with red if red was entered first? That the key question of all this case sir.

Comment: what about if cherry was entered first and Food after and then food wants to establish a grandparent relationship with RED? or vice verse.

Comment: is there an database model that could be done or maybe creating other fields for relation

Comment: ok, I can see that if a node is inserted above a parent, there should be an update in the subsequent parent_id s and the categories_id s which will have to update and INSERT at the same time?

Comment: insert into categories(parent_id, name) 
    values(2, 'blue');
What about if the user doesn't know which parent id is who? and instead it refers to the parent_id by the name, if the know the name red them automatically the insert will insert parent_id. so far as above.

Comment: Hey mikael I pulled out the category_id where name=parent then took the id of the parent and inserted as the parent_id of the fish hook. Great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want left_node and right_node NOT NULL? What value do you use for a leaf (e.g., banana)? Doesn't matter for this question.

You appear to be using MySQL, which does not implement the best way to answer this question. You want a **recursive CTE**. However, as a hack, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW parents AS 
SELECT c.category_id AS parent, 
 c2.category_id AS child
FROM categories c JOIN categories c2 
ON c2.category_id=c.left_node OR c2.category_id=c.right_node;
```

You can now get the first level with

```
SELECT child FROM parents
WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM parents);
```

The NOT IN subquery returns the root. To get an arbitrary level, as far as I know, you need a recursive or iterative procedure or a database that allows recursive CTE, or more horrid views.

[edit: you can do this in one hard-to-read SELECT

```
SELECT child FROM parents
    WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM
        (  SELECT c.category_id AS parent, 
     c2.category_id AS child
    FROM categories c JOIN categories c2 
    ON c2.category_id=c.left_node OR c2.category_id=c.right_node) AS anyname);
```

]

Comment: @Andrew I have a question with the mysql database as a server I will have to update the mysql database so it can suport recursive CTE or I will have to install a new sql server that support recursive CTE server. And what if I intall the recursive CTE server will still support Mysql queries as of now?

Comment: Postgresql is open source and handles a lot of advanced SQL constructs, many more than MySQL. However, it is larger and many people believe slower. (You can find a lot of discussion about that on the Internet!) It might be easier to write a MySQL function that used a loop to go from an arbitrary node to the root. You can also keep a 'parent' field. It introduces redundant information into the table that will have to be kept valid with a trigger, but it makes it MUCH easier to go from a record up to the parent (from which you know the level.)

Comment: how can I use the first select with CREATE VIEW as reference to the second? I was wondering how can I use to SELECT in one query?

Comment: Just take where it says "parents" in the second query and paste in the SELECT of the view definition.

Comment: it will be something like that?                                SELECT child FROM (SELECT c.category_id AS parent, 
 c2.category_id AS child
FROM categories c JOIN categories c2 
ON c2.category_id=c.left_node OR c2.category_id=c.right_node;
)
WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM parents);

Comment: the SELECT goes in between parenthesis? so it will call child the elements within the same level other tahn the one being called?

Comment: Excuseme but I haven't seen the field name, does it need to be selected in order to be echo?                                                                                   There is an fatal error right now      

 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias' in

Comment: I have a functions.php and then in children.php I have the instantiation but it seem s like something is going on with the alias which is not even displaying the name

Comment: full error   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias' in /public_html/parent/scripts/functions.php:101 Stack trace: #0 /home3/nyhungry/public_html/parent/scripts/functions.php(101): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /public_html/parent/Fruits.php(126): hierachy->getSamelevelNode('Fruit') #2 {main} thrown in /public_html/parent/scripts/functions.php on line 101

Comment: You do not need a recursive CTE to get nodes of the same depth in a nested set model. Instead just self join and count the nodes higher than the current one. See: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: @a'r Which of the queries in there you suggest for this particular situation? I was thinking about a Retrieving a Single Path query. Have a suggestion?

Comment: You need to have a table alias for the subquery. Sorry. (See revised code.) Note that the a'r solution requires you to intercept INSERT and DELETE statements. The recursive CTE was added to SQL for pretty much exactly this situation: it makes the queries much easier to read.

Comment: @Andrew ok alias subquery, in this case subquery means still in the same level? I just realized that as the sql statement is subquery it interpret it as level of depth and depending on the ORDER BY it will go upward or downward

Comment: @Andrew i imagine that's why you used the NOT IN so taht the SQL statement don't interpret it as another level.

Comment: @Andrew it is trowing a couple of fatal error saying there is some of the tables that doesn't exist.

Comment: I having an error General error: 1349 View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause' in /public_html/parent/scripts/functions.php:129 Stack trace: ("CREATE VIEW parents AS (SELECT child FROM parents WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM (SELECT c.category_id AS parent, c2.category_id AS child FROM categories c JOIN categories c2 ON c2.category_id = c.left_node OR c2.category_id = c.right_node) AS level1))");

Answer (score 0):

`$node_name` is the node whose direct children are to be returned:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c
  INNER JOIN categories p ON c.left_node > p.left_node AND c.right_node < p.right_node
  LEFT JOIN categories g  ON g.left_node > p.left_node AND g.right_node < p.right_node
                         AND g.left_node < c.left_node AND g.right_node > c.right_node
WHERE p.name = '{$node_name}' AND g.category_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Andriy, I am wondering if my web host would be ok if I use cte server 2005+ statements. I guess most of the web hosts should support CTE.

Comment: do I have to SELECT all the rows like WITH categories (category_id, name, left_node, right_node) AS (   SELECT  1, 'Food',    1, 18 UNION ALL   SELECT  2, 'Fruit',   2, 11 UNION ALL   SELECT  3, 'Red',     3,  6 UNION ALL   SELECT  4, 'Cherry',  4,  5 UNION ALL   SELECT  5, 'Yellow',  7, 10 UNION ALL   SELECT  6, 'Banana',  8,  9 UNION ALL   SELECT  7, 'Meat',   12, 17 UNION ALL   SELECT  8, 'Beef',   13, 14 UNION ALL   SELECT  9, 'Pork',   15, 16 ?

Comment: when you say Assuming @parent_id is the ID of the item whose direct children are to be returned: what do you mean by that? in the table structu that field doesn't exist, or it just some temporary field created as a reference to the fields related to the node being called? or I will have to create a field in the database for @parent_id?

Comment: Some database servers support CTEs, some others don't. I don't know what's your database server so I can't tell you whether you can use CTEs. But as for my solution, you just don't need the CTE I've included. It's only used as a substitute for the real table, and you've already got the real table. So just ignore the CTE and use the part starting from `SELECT c.*` onwards.

Comment: As for the @parent_id, that was just my assumption of how you would probably specify which row of data should be returned. I assumed you would specify the immediate parent of the items wanted and I also assumed you would specify that parent by its ID. If my assumption is wrong, you may want to clarify that bit so I can modify my solution accordingly.

Comment: I was comparing it by the name or You mean using the @ symbol in that part referring to the node id selected by the user or the target?

Comment: really I thought the row of data was going to be return by the instruction given by SELECT WHERE and ON, of course with the help of that condition on the @parent_id but I don't understand which parent_id I will compare it to because the only fields in the tables are category_id, left_node, right_node, name.

Comment: I changed my solution so now it accepts the name of the parent, similar to your queries in other questions. If you specify `FOOD`, the query returns `FRUIT` and `MEAT`, `RED` returns `CHERRY`.

Comment: I have that query already this thread is if FRUIT is requested then display MEAT. Not from parent to child but same level relationship. or if MEAT is requested then FRUIT will be display, If RED is specify then YELLOW will be return if CHERRY is specify then nothing is going to be return because there is nothing in their level it is by itself.

Comment: Tested in the sql and it returned the child of FRUIT RED not MEAT instead. looking to return Meat when Fruit is specify.