# how can I relate two nodes in different rows in a nested model tree?

Tags: sql

[image]

how can I  relate Fruit and Meat when Fruit or Meat are call and display both of them? I have use a couple of calculations in between their nodes numbers 2,11,12,17 ran out of calculus. can you think of a equation to solve this problem?

Comment: I answered what the question appears to be asking, but you might need to provide more details, such as a Table Schema and maybe even a few example rows of data. For example, why does each entry have 2 numbers instead of just 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a query to display nodes in the same level only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762913/looking-for-a-query-to-display-nodes-in-the-same-level-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each entry needs to have a "parent" association so you know how to build the tree. You can relate those nodes as they would have the same parent. Or if you needed to relate items at a particular level, such "Red" and "Beef", that would require something like a recursive CTE in SQL Server 2005 or newer.

Comment: I might think to relate "Red and Beef" later on, as well the table schema is as below, I just simply started workin on this nested model with two number, I guess it would facilitate and give more options to calculations and possibilities to relate like nodes in the same level, and even go farther relating Red and Beef as you suggested.